# Is there a way to not restart the app after each test in Appium with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

my code looks something like this:

```
def goToDashboard(self):
    desired_cap = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "12",
        "deviceName": "Pixel 6",
        "appActivity": ".MainActivity",
        "appWaitActivity": ".MainActivity",
        "appPackage": "com.test.test",
        "app": "C:\\test\\test-app-release.apk",
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
    bp = BasePage(driver)
    return driver
```

I am using this goToDashboard function in my first test like this:

```
def test_AddDevice():

driver1 = Driver()
driver = driver1.goToDashboard()
bp = BasePage(driver)
```

Is there a way not to restart the app after each test? I am pretty new to Appium and python and would appreciate a warm answer. Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on the framework that we're using.